# Tabelas de MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, inner-join

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como mostra a imagem, tenho a tabela `adms_unidade` onde já consigo mostrar as unidades listadas, e tenho a tabela `adms_equipamentos` com vários equipamentos cadastrados.

Quero mostrar quantos equipamentos cadastrados possuo em cada unidade usando o `adms_unidade_id` que é a chave estrangeira da `tablea adms_equipamentos` referente a chave `primary` da tabela `adms_unidades`.

já vi alguns exemplos e maneiras, mas não sei se é erro de digitação ou não.

Comment: Faça um INNER JOIN das tabelas e utilize a função de agregação COUNT com a clausula GROUP BY. Postar imagens no lugar dos códigos não é uma atitude bem vista neste site, o mesmo para não postar o código da consulta que tentou com a explicação de porque considera o resultado errado.

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

basta fazer a ligação da tabela `adms_equipamentos` com a `adms_unidades` com `left outer join`, no caso de não existir equipamentos cadastrados para aquela unidade, e então você agrupa pela unidade e conta quantos registros existem para cada agrupamento.

```
select au.nome_da_unidade, count(*) qtd_equipamentos
from adms_unidades au
left outer join adms_equipamentos ae
on ae.adms_unidade_id = au.id
group by au.nome_da_unidade
```